# I use https to request my authorization api and message shows unauthorized

Tags: hmac, api-gateway, kong

I according to the kong documentation

[image: hmac doc]

I create a http route and I use http to request api, I get ok 200.

I also create a https route and I use https request api, I get 401 unauthorize

[image: i add credential and i make an authorized request]

I am very confused, http request its ok but https request its show unauthorize
Forgive my bad english

Comment: Please don't post [picture](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) Can you share your  route configuration ? have you set http and https ?
Can you do the request adding the header `X-Kong-Debug: 1`  ?

Comment: ok  i fix it because I had misunderstood the documentation before.

Comment: i have a new problem :my constom SSL certificate does not work

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69792993/my-constum-ssl-certificate-does-not-work-kong     i opne a new  issue  Can you help me with this?